# Controlling multiple audio files from images on webpage

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I'm fairly new to web development so apologies if I am missing the obvious!

I have a page where I have a series of images each associated with an audio file.

I have 'borrowed' some JS to stop audio A when audio B is clicked (audio B then plays), however I would also like to be able to pause audio A by clicking on the image a second time. Or preferably open the audio controls for whichever image (and associated audio file) is clicked.

The code looks like this;

```html
<body>

<audio id='spokes'>
  <source src="tunes/Spokes.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
  <source src="tunes/Spokes.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
</audio>

<audio id='raptor'>
  <source src="tunes/raptor.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
  <source src="tunes/raptor.ogg" type="audio/mpeg" />
</audio>


<section>
<img class="trigger" src="img/spokes.png" onclick="document.getElementById('spokes').play()" />
<p>Spokes</p>
</section>

<section>
<img class="trigger" src="img/raptor.png" onclick="document.getElementById('raptor').play()" />
<p>Raptor</p>
</section>

<script type="text/javascript">
  document.addEventListener('play', function(e){
    var audios = document.getElementsByTagName('audio');
    for(var i = 0, len = audios.length; i < len;i++){
        if(audios[i] != e.target){
            audios[i].pause();
            audios[i].currentTime = 0;
        }
    }
}, true);
</script>

</body>
```

Comment: The simplest approach would be to keep a variable reflecting the state of the playback for each audio, and capture the `click` (using `onClick`), check the status of the variable corresponding to clicked image/audio as well as that of the others, and act on the playback (of all audios) accordingly.

Comment: Hi FDavidov thanks for the response - can I just check how to do this, would I still use the onclick event in the html - i.e.  onclick="document.getElementById('spokes').play()" . Does this need to be a separate script or would it work with the existing JS?

Comment: I would suggest you create a simple method (function) within your script that would be invoked along with a single parameter: the ID of the clicked image/audio. The script will then check the status of the clicked image/audio as well as that of the others and (as mentioned in my previous) act accordingly (i.e. pause the current if it was the one playing, stop the one that was playing and start the current, etc.).

Comment: Thanks for your help! I've found a different approach for this - on click the audio controls are opened, this works great on a specific audio/ image but what I need to do is pass a variable for the target audio instead of the document.getelementbyId in the below;                      var audio = document.getElementById('spokes');

function toggleControls() {
  if (audio.hasAttribute("controls")) {
     audio.removeAttribute("controls")   
  } else {
     audio.setAttribute("controls","controls")   
  }
}

Can I use an EventListener or similar to get the audio ID of the current audio?

Comment: [I'm guessing here...] You get the list of images/audios from some DB, file, or a search result, and then deploy into your page the images logically linked to the audio files. During the deployment, you can include on each image something like `onClick="Handle_Image_Click(<image_ID>)`. Within your JS, the function `Handle_Image_Click` will manage objects that would reflect the status of each and every audio file (play/pause/stopped), and trigger the correct action of the audio linked to the clicked image (and other audio if needed). Hope this is now clear.

Comment: That's great, thanks - I think I understand (only down to my lack of knowledge, not your explanation!) and will have a go...

Comment: I'm glad my input was of help. Will appreciate you up-vote my comments (that way I get a little push up to my reputation :-)).

Comment: How do I upvote if it's a comment and not an Answer?? (Sorry I am also new to Stack Overflow!!)

Comment: If you move your mouse over a comment (not yours), you will see at the left of the comment two items, a flag and an up-arrow. Simply click on the up-arrow (you get tooltips when hovering the mouse over those elements). Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use the `paused` property.

Create a function for playing/pausing your audio player.

```
function playPause(id){
    var audio = document.getElementById(id);
    if(audio.paused){
        play(audio);
    }
    else if(!audio.paused && myAudio.duration <= 0){
        play(audio);
    }
    else{
        audio.pause();
    }
}


function play(audio){
    var playVideo = audio.play();
        if (playVideo !== undefined) {
            playVideo .then(_ => {
            console.log("Video playing...")
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log("could not play video");
        });
}
```

Then use the function and target the id of the audio tag

```
<img class="trigger" src="img/spokes.png" onclick="playPause('spokes')" />
```

**EDIT**

`play()` is asynchronous. I've updated code to show this. Thanks to @Idan Beker

Comment: This is no longer the case (on chrome at least) , where the play function returns a promise.

for more insight: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/06/play-request-was-interrupted

Comment: Thanks Ayo that's helpful. I've tried the code but it's now not playing the audio on first click - do I need to add an audio.play() call before the If statement? I.e. so that onclick the function is called, which starts the audio playing, then on a second click it pauses audio?

Comment: Thanks for your help! I've found a different approach for this - on click the audio controls are opened, this works great on a specific audio/ image but what I need to do is pass a variable for the target audio instead of the document.getelementbyId in the below; var audio = document.getElementById('spokes'); function toggleControls() { if (audio.hasAttribute("controls")) { audio.removeAttribute("controls") } else { audio.setAttribute("controls","controls") } } Can I use an EventListener or similar to get the audio ID of the current audio?